# How to disable this in visual studio code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, configuration, hover

[image]

I'm new to programming in Python and I'm using Visual Studio Code. I have the issue that sometimes a box with certain specifications appears while coding, and I don't understand it. It's also bothersome, and I'd like to remove it. How can I do that?

[image]

I tried to deactivate something called "hover," but there are many options, and I don't know which one to deactivate.